# is it impossible to use clipboard on aws(amazon-web-service) ubuntu18.04 instance?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, clipboard, ubuntu-18.04, pyperclip

I've trying to use python library which is called pyperclip 
on AWS EC2 Ubuntu18.04 with jupyter-notebook.
when I import pyperclip and test if its copy() function works properly,

`import pyperclip
pyperclip.copy(2)`

I continually get this error.

```
PyperclipException: 
Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.
For more information, please visit https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error
```

I've searched for few days and installed all things seemed to be needed.
(xclip,xsel,pygi,and PyQt5)
But It still doesn't work.

Does anyone knows how to handle this???

Comment: I think you need some sort of clipboard tool to be installed on the machine, try running "apt-get install xclip"

Comment: I already installed xclip but when I check xclip version I got this error.               
root@ip-172-31-20-72:~# xclip version
Error: Can't open display: (null)

Comment: sorry, don't have much else to suggest, was just a guess :)

Comment: any solution yet?